# Firefox renders table incorrect with multiple rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, firefox

The following code works well in Chrome and IE, but does not working in Firefox.

The `table` is generated dynamically and `tr`/`td` can't be removed from the following example

```css
.widget-table-container,
tr td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.widget {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="widget-table-container">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="width: 378px; height: 378px;">
        <div class="widget" style="width: 371px; height: 371px; background-color:lightblue;">
          <div class="widget-title">
            <p>Title</p>
          </div>
          <div class="widget-body"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="8" rowspan="4" style="width: 1512px; height: 756px;">
        <div class="widget" style="width: 1493px; height: 745px;">
          <div class="widget-title">Title CPU</p>
          </div>
          <div class="widget-body">BODY</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="width: 378px; height: 378px;">
        <div class="widget" style="width: 371px; height: 371px;">
          <div class="widget-title">
            <p>Some Title</p>
          </div>
          <div class="widget-body"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you saying you can't remove the `colspan`/`rowspan` attributes as well?

Comment: Hi, yes, I need them for width and height calculations, because these widgets can be resized by user and i need to know how much cells needed for widget.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed last empty  and it looks like fixed problem.
I'm not sure why only removing last tr fixed problem not all tr.
But i my case it is working, Thanks All for help.